# BBCLASSEXTEND="native nativesdk"

Tags: build, yocto, openembedded

After checked the official document, I still don’t understand this meaning in recipe.

```
BBCLASSEXTEND="native nativesdk"
```

Comment: It allows a normal recipe to be extended to a native recipe (and can be included in a host part SDK).

Answer (score 9):

`BBCLASSEXTEND` is a way for the named classes (in this case, `native` and `nativesdk`) to run over the recipe to alter them.

The native class makes a version of the recipe (with `-native` appended to the name) that builds for the build host instead of the build target, so you can execute the binaries during the build.  The nativesdk class is similar but builds packages to be executed in the SDK.

Comment: Does that mean that I set `BBCLASSEXTEND = ""` if my recipe is only meant to be built for the target machine architecture?

Comment: In that case, don't set `BBCLASSEXTEND` (which is the same as setting to `""`).